# Sampling data points from a Gaussian Mixture Model python

Tags: python, scikit-learn, data-science, gaussian, mixture-model

I am really new to python and GMM. I learned GMM recently and trying to implement the codes from [here](https://jakevdp.github.io/PythonDataScienceHandbook/05.12-gaussian-mixtures.html)

I met some problems when I run gmm.sample() method:

```
gmm16 = GaussianMixture(n_components=16, covariance_type='full', random_state=0)    
Xnew = gmm16.sample(400,random_state=42)
plt.scatter(Xnew[:, 0], Xnew[:, 1])
```

the error shows:

```
TypeError: sample() got an unexpected keyword argument 'random_state'
```

I have checked the latest document and find out the method sample should only contain n which indicates that the number of samples to generate. But when I delete 'random_state=42', new error appears:

codes:

```
Xnew = gmm16.sample(400)
plt.scatter(Xnew[:, 0], Xnew[:, 1])
```

error:

```
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

Does anyone meet this problem when you implement the codes from Jake VanderPlas? How could I fix it?

My Jupyter:

> The version of the notebook server is: 5.7.4
>
> Python 3.7.1 (default, Dec 14 2018, 13:28:58)
>
> Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
>
> IPython 7.2.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You get the `TypeError` because the `sample` method returns a `tuple`, see [here](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.html#sklearn.mixture.GaussianMixture.sample).

This should do the job:

```
Xnew, Ynew = gmm16.sample(400)  # if Ynew is valuable
plt.scatter(Xnew[:, 0], Xnew[:, 1])
```

or

```
Xnew, _ = gmm16.sample(400)  # if Ynew isn't valuable
plt.scatter(Xnew[:, 0], Xnew[:, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is in the way you are feeding the data to the scatter plot.
Particularly you have a numpy array inside a tuple and the way you are indexing is incorrect.
Try this.

```
plt.scatter(Xnew[0][:,0], Xnew[0][:,1])
```

Basically what we have is that the first indexing `Xnew[0]` will point to the element in the tuple you want (the numpy array) and the second will slice it as you need. `[:,1]` Here we take all the rows and the second column.